# Mobile view on my website, and other imaging questions

Tags: css, wordpress

I built a wordpress website through godaddy (not sure if that is relevant or not), I used the Sydney Theme which fits my needs for the most part, and I use a NextGen gallery widget for my portfolio pages.
When I go into the Mobile view of my website, it takes the thumbnails, and lines them up in one column which makes perfect sense, but it lines that column up left justified, while the rest of the website is centered...this is a minor thing, but bugs the hell out of me.
I wrote back and forth with the theme support, and they cant figure it out, suggest i hire someone. I went back and forth with the gallery support, they blame the theme, and have no help to offer. I have tried other galleries one of which I like very much, but I cant get it to behave correctly at all, (its by web-dorado, and when I click next picture it goes to the last picture and then runs backwards through the series, makes me look like an idiot) When I tried to get help from the second gallery widget group, they wanted administrative rights to my website, and I just cant see doing that.
Long story short, I need some help, if anyone has the time.
My second question is much easier, my theme resizes for the different screen sizes so on and so forth, is there a standard "max" size, is it in the theme itself? I have a slider on the homepage, and my images in it are HUGE, i want to shrink them so it loads a little faster, but I do not know what the standard size is, while still maintaining the integrity of the image (im a photo guy). THANKS!

Comment: If it helps, the website is eppicmedia.com

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your theme `style.css` file:

```
@media (max-width: 380px) {
    .ngg-widget img {
        float: none !important;
        margin: auto !important;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

For the slider you can use any size since it uses the background image css rule so there is no "max" size.  If you like how it looks right now resize your images keeping the same aspect ratio. You can also try free image optimizers to reduce the size.